# Selenium EdgeDriver options

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-edgedriver

How do I integrate selenium webdriver Edge options into EdgeDriver in python?

I tried to use:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

# with

from selenium.webdriver import Edge
```

PS: I do not want to use another package like *[msedge](https://pypi.org/project/msedge-selenium-tools/)* :)

Comment: Did you look at the docs? What did you find there?

Comment: Depending on the version, this is not clear. But in version 4 or higher it seems to be easier

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Note: `Options` were introduced in Selenium 4. In order to use options, you need to upgrade your selenium to version 4/higher.

Comment: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'EdgeOptions' with selenium 3.141.0

Comment: Check the Note in the updated answer.

Comment: Hey, I am not really confident about "experimental" options. Is there a specific version of Selenium that allow EdgeWebdriver to have "add_option" instead of "add_experimental_option"?